# How do I increment a number in middle of the string

Tags: shell

I am trying to increment a number in the middle of the string. Tried many ways but didn't find a solution. Any ideas in shell script
Ex:- i have a string sam_2.0_protected_dev_branch. I want to increment the number at the middle of the string. So the output should look like
sam_2.0_kumar_dev_branch
sam_2.1_kumar_dev_branch
sam_2.2_kumar_dev_branch
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of trying to change the string, divide it in 3 parts. text, number and text. you can increment the number and then make one string with that 3 parts.

Sorry if the terminology isn't right

here is a proper documentation: https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-concat.html

Code :

```
$version = 1.0
$nameOne = "sam_"
$nametwo = "_protected_dev_branch"

for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++)
{ 
    $fullName = $nameOne + $version + $nametwo

    Write-Host $fullName
    $version = $version + 0.1
}
```

Output :

```
sam_1_protected_dev_branch
sam_1.1_protected_dev_branch
sam_1.2_protected_dev_branch
sam_1.3_protected_dev_branch
```

there's a way to to force a number to show number of numbers after the comma, but I will let you deal with it

---

```
    $version = 1
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++)
{ 
    $fullName = "sam_2." + $version + "_protected_dev_branch"
    Write-Host $fullName
    $version = $version + 1
}
```

Comment: I have tried to split the string into strings and numbers. 
$  echo sam_2.0_kumar_dev_branch | sed 's/[a-zA-Z]*\|[0-9]*/&\n/g; s/\n$//'
Output:-
sam
_2
.0
_kumar
_dev
_branch

Comment: @SampathKumarEsikala I have added the exact code, but it may need to be finished, I will let you do it. It shouldn't be that hard. Also I don't know exactly what shell you're using or if there's even a difference but this was done in PowerShell

Comment: Instead of splitting numbers and strings. Can we do in this way.
sam_2.0_kumar_dev_branch replace .0 with $i and iterate in a loop to increment the value of i ?
ex:-
sam_2.0_kumar_dev_branch -> sam_2.$i_kumar_dev_branch
Using sed we can replace a character at particular position.

Comment: I don't know if you could, but even if it worked, the code has to change if you ever decide to release 3.0 version. up to you

Comment: I added the way you said, doesn't really change much to be honest

Comment: The approach/idea given works. Now i am able to get the desired output.
Thanks for the idea.